# SchemaCrawler for Oracle is running for too long

Tags: schemacrawler

Even for fetching the schema for a single table its taking a lot of time and then failing. Though, the source DB schema contains number of tables in 1000s

```
$ schemacrawler --shell
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
schemacrawler>
schemacrawler> connect --user=XXX --password=XXXXXX--database=XXXXX--host=XXXXX.sss.se.com --port=1523 --server=oracle
connect --user=XXX --password=XXXXXX--database=XXXXX--host=XXXXX.sss.se.com --port=1523 --server=oracle
schemacrawler>
schemacrawler> limit --tables=.*GL_JE_LINES
limit --tables=.*GL_JE_LINES
schemacrawler>
schemacrawler> load --info-level=standard
load --info-level=standard
```

ERROR: Cannot load catalog

```
Using the above with Lambda which has 15 minutes as threshold time.
```

Comment: Please see https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/issues/1346